# limiting primary key sqlite android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am working with SQLITE database in android, I have read if we insert null in integer primary key, it use some algo, and generate unique integer primary key.
my question, is there any way to limit integer primary key, for e.g It should generate integer number between some range, lets suppose between 1 and 100. after 100 it should go for 1 or any empty number between

Comment: You shouldn't ever reuse primary keys. A primary key should uniquely ID a row in a table, and if that row gets deleted, ideally you should never reuse that key. What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: according to my logic, I need to limit primary key.

Comment: Why? What logic? What's your use case? What's your requirement that you feel that limiting your primary keys fulfills.

Comment: I think in android the concept of primary key is it automatically increments the value.
If you try to limit the value then you may not be allowed to enter any more values after the limit (It may throw error)

Comment: I am making alarm clock, which can set unlimited alarms, now every alarm has unique id, which I am using as code in pending intent.
and now I want unique code in pending intent, from which I will be snoozing alarm.
If I use a same code, It will override the previous pending intent

Comment: I am not sure whether this works or not but give a try
use a column isSnoozed in the database and if we are trying to snooze it set it to true else set it to false.
then call the pending intent on each and every row which has isSnoozed as true

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question - yes it is possible with the help of a TRIGGER (BEFORE INSERT). I never used it on Android and I'm not quit sure if Android will support this - but this would be the way to go.

BUT, limiting the PK is not what you want to do. This sounds like a poor design. A Primary Key stays forever. It's a key, the key, nothing but the key.

Any additional logic must be done with the help of additional columns.

[SQLite Create Trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)